# golang in goland kinesis.GetRecordsInput is not found while the method is?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-kinesis, goland

[image: GetRecordsInput]

Why is it that GetRecordsInput is not found?  What are the possible reasons for this not compiling?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhhhhhh, if you have a variable like so

```
 kinesis := {whatever}
```

well, you just screwed yourself!!!  But of course to add to the confusion kinesis.GetRecords was working just fine.  This took me a good hour of looking into before I tried some whacky stuff and thought outside the box.  grrrrrr.

Comment: The IDE should suggest that you named your variable after the package name, which will shadow it. I think in your screenshot it's also highlighted with the underline. Have you tried pressing Alt+Enter there or checking why it's underlined? If not why not? I'm asking because I would like to take this as feedback for the team to improve the usability/discoverability in this case.

Comment: @dlsniper Sorry, all it said was 'Unresolved Type'.  It was pretty confusing.